# FullCalendar Resource view, change cell background color

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the Full calendar Resource View of jarnokurlin (https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar), which was an extension of Full calendar of AdamShow.

My issues is I want to indicate the holidays in the time line by changing the cell background color in front of each resource. Different resources may be from different countries so I have to change the colors of the day cells accordingly.

How to do this?

Comment: Share you code kindly

Comment: Hi, my code is a mess. You can find the initial one in here "https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar"

Answer (score 1):

Your question is old, but still relevant. Here is a solution, I think: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events

You can create a new event which apears in the background, not like the others.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 events: [{
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                        backgroundColor: '#000'
                    }, {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
                        backgroundColor: '#dedede',
                    },
}]

});
```

Comment: This is for Full Calendar. But I need to change color in the time line of the individual resources.